# Turn letters to number not working python

Tags: python, string

I have this code in python:

```
lettonum = {
  "a":1,
  "b":2,
  "c":3
}
def tonum(eput):
  output = ""
  doing = 1
  for _ in range(len(eput)):
    mys = lettonum[eput[doing]]
    output = f"{output}{mys}"
    doing = doing + 1
  print(output)

while True:
  tonum(input("String to be encoded to numbers: "))
```

Basically, it is supposed to turn letters a, b, and c to numbers 1, 2, and 3

I put in

```
String to be encoded to numbers: abc
```

but it throws this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    tonum(input("String to be encoded to numbers: "))
  File "main.py", line 13, in tonum
    mys = lettonum[eput[doing]]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Indexes in python start at zero not one. It’s not clear why you aren’t using the value from the for loop.

Comment: So do I need to plus one? Sorry, I'm new to loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python discourages looping over ranges unless you really need the indices. Doing `for index in range(len(something)):` then `something[index]` is a waste when python lets you more easily just iterate over the values directly. One of the main advantages of this is that you avoid the *very* common indexing problems you are experiencing:

```
lettonum = {
    "a":1,
    "b":2,
    "c":3
}

def tonum(eput):
    output = ""
    for letter in eput:
        mys = lettonum[letter]
        output += str(mys)
    print(output)


tonum('abc')
# 123
```

Answer (score 1):

You should start indexing from 0, not 1:

```
lettonum = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3
}


def tonum(eput):
    global lettonum
    output = ""
    doing = 0
    for _ in range(len(eput)):
        mys = lettonum[eput[doing]]
        output = f"{output}{mys}"
        doing = doing + 1
    print(output)


while True:
    tonum(input("String to be encoded to numbers: "))
```

Or alternative (and better) solution with indexing:

```
def tonum(eput):
    global lettonum
    output = ""
    for doing in range(len(eput)):
        mys = lettonum[eput[doing]]
        output = f"{output}{mys}"
    print(output)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure, sir! And if my or any other answer to the original question was helpful, feel free to mark it as right.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes start from 0, not 1.

```
lettonum = {
  "a":1,
  "b":2,
  "c":3
}
def tonum(eput):
  output = ""
  doing = 1
  for _ in range(len(eput)):
    mys = lettonum[eput[doing]]
    output = f"{output}{mys}"
    doing = doing + 1
  print(output)

while True:
  tonum(input("String to be encoded to numbers: "))
```